# Bing Search API -The authorization type you provided is not supported(ios)

Tags: bing-api

I am making use of Bing Search API available on Windows Azure Marketplace.

`Subscription Type: Bing Search API (5000 transactions per month free).`

I have obtained the account key.

Still I get response as

```
**The authorization type you provided is not supported.Only Basic and OAuth are supported**
```

When I copy url in the browser it asks for the user name and password (only password is mandatory and it is nothing but the account key) and after validating I can see data in XML/JSON format.

How I can achieve this through my program?

My code is:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s","https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?$format=json&$top=8&Query='querystring'"];  
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]) ;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] ;

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start] ;
```

Comment: Add following function in the code for authorization [code]-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLCredential *cred = [[[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:Account_key password:Account_key
                                                       persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession] autorelease];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}